# Production environment getting error 401 (Code: 701 - Wrong authentication credentials) when calling any amadeus api endpoint

Tags: authentication, production-environment, http-status-code-401, amadeus

Using the Postman collection for Amadeus for Developers I can successfully get access token and execute any api endpoint in the test environment (test.api.amadeus.com)

But after signing up successfully for Production Environment (without Flight Create Offer), I am able to get access token from Production (api.amadeus.com) BUT all api endpoint execution results in 401 error (Code: 701 - Wrong authentication credentials)

Below is the error in postman

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "status": 401,
        "code": 701,
        "title": "Wrong authentication credentials.",
        "source": {
            "pointer": "uri"
        }
    }
]
```

}

i have made sure the bearer token is valid and my api calls are pointed to api.amadeus.com using the Prodction Key and Secret.

I have been in contact with Amadeus email helpline (self-service.apis@amadeus.com) for the last 3 weeks, and after each week they instructed me to reset my account password and wait 2 hours before making the call, which i did three times now and ended up with the same error.

I hope someone higher in the tech department will notice my question and will be able to shed some light as to why your system is not letting me call production environment.

will be eagerly waiting for some advise.....

Comment: Hi, did you try with Postman for production? in your comment, you only used Postman for test environment. Tell me

Comment: yes i did change my environment to production and made sure all calls are pointed to https://api.amadeus.com uri

Comment: Hi Sunny, can you share the code that you have the issue? Is it related to Flight Create Orders API?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well, try to generate an access token few more times and use it, for me is suddenly worked

Comment: i have tried generating access token in my production environment several times since you posted that comment. but all my attempts have failed...